# Looking for a font to imitate dementia / dyslexia

Tags: fonts, typography

I'm trying to produce an image from the point of view of a person with dementia who can no longer make sense of signage. The feeling is that the forms are very familiar, but don't come together as real words any more, which makes it frustrating.

There are a couple of examples of this for explaining dyslexia, e.g. [this one](https://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/07/11/31F3D21100000578-0-image-a-29_1457349263043.jpg), and I've found one font here on SE called [Hacker Argot](https://www.dafont.com/hacker-argot.font) , but if anyone knows of a serif that would be amazing. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thats not what dyslexia looks like. It quite literally does look like normal text it just does not arrive as correct reading. Anyway i feel its irresponsible to claim that something looks like dementia/dyslexia. Thats just a lie, for one each case is different.

Comment: In addition to @joojaa’s point, dementia and dyslexia are two **completely** different things, and text won’t have anything like the same type of effect on sufferers of them.

Comment: @joojaa and Janus, I appreciate the difference from plenty of personal and family experience, however I was already confident that nobody has created a typeface to simulate dementia. I also know that people _have_ tried to do it for dyslexia, and for my purposes (a background detail in an illustration which is not educational) that would be good enough to get the idea across. Perhaps a better description would be 'a typeface which simulates illiteracy'. And yes, I understand that dyslexia is not illiteracy, because I'm able to write this :-)

Comment: What I'm going for is the typographical equivalent of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vt4Dfa4fOEY

Comment: If you just want to simulate illiteracy, depending on your audience, creating all the text in Cyrillic or Chinese would be sufficient. Chinese is especially useful because the average non-Chinese speaker would be unable even to look the words up in a dictionary. (No smartphones allowed or the illusion falls to pieces though).

Answer (score 0):

I think you *could* merely scramble letters in words...

...but if you want something more, there are fonts like [**halffont**](https://fontesk.com/half-typeface/#:%7E:text=Half%20is%20a%20creative%20modern,merchandise%20and%20other%20unique%20artworks.)

Comment: Thanks Scott! I might try that and throw in some Cyrillic and ligatured characters not used in English.

Comment: Yeah, Noto Sans has a lot of characters from languages like Georgian which are rendered in forms that look like they might be letters in our alphabet but aren't, and a lot of symbols too, all in the same style. Checking through the Noto Sans versions for characters which don't read as a specific foreign alphabet could get you what you want.